# Status icon in GTK+ on MacOSX, Windows, and Linux(Gnome) and python

Tags: python, macos, cross-platform, pygtk, system-tray

I'm developing an application in python and it will be used in Windows MacOsX and Linux, and now i'm developing system (status icon) icon (and the menu when you click) in Mac OSX bar.
Can I use PyGTK in windows, mac and linux and use the same code for show status icon in status bar (macosx), system tray(windows), or linux?

Thanks in advance.
This is the code:

```
import gtk


class SystrayIconApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tray = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.tray.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT) 
        self.tray.connect('popup-menu', self.on_right_click)
        self.tray.set_tooltip(('Sample tray app'))


        def on_right_click(self, icon, event_button, event_time):
          self.make_menu(event_button, event_time)

        def make_menu(self, event_button, event_time):
          menu = gtk.Menu()

          # show about dialog
          about = gtk.MenuItem("About")
          about.show()
          menu.append(about)
          about.connect('activate', self.show_about_dialog)

          # add quit item
          quit = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
          quit.show()
          menu.append(quit)
          quit.connect('activate', gtk.main_quit)

          menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu,
                   event_button, event_time, self.tray)

    def  show_about_dialog(self, widget):
        about_dialog = gtk.AboutDialog()
        about_dialog.set_destroy_with_parent (True)
        about_dialog.set_icon_name ("SystrayIcon")
        about_dialog.set_name('SystrayIcon')
        about_dialog.set_version('0.1')
        about_dialog.set_copyright("(C) 2010 João Pinto")
        about_dialog.set_comments(("Program to demonstrate a system tray icon"))
        about_dialog.set_authors(['João Pinto <joao.pinto@getdeb.net>'])
        about_dialog.run()
        about_dialog.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SystrayIconApp()
    gtk.main()
```

This is de tray in MAC OS X (the star from gtk+):

[image: This is system tray in MAC OS X]

This is the tray in WINDOWS (the star from gtk+):

[image: This is the tray in WINDOWS]

On windows no problem, menu is visible when you click the icon, but in Mac OX, icos is showed but menu is not displayed.

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "status bar icon" ? The icons shown in the system's tray in Windows ? Because this behavior only exists in Windows, you don't have any icons in the system's tray on Gnome anymore (3.4+). Maybe you're talking about the application's icon?

Comment: Star Icon on upper images

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? For adding indicator icon on OSX using Python Gtk (or PyGObject / Gtk+3).

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Yes !

Qt manages the status icons integration in all compatible operating systems.

You just have to use the `QSystemTrayIcon` class in order to do that.

> The QSystemTrayIcon class provides an icon for an application in the system tray.
>   Modern operating systems usually provide a special area on the desktop, called the system tray or notification area, where long-running applications can display icons and short messages.

More information on the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html).

Comment: But I want do a commercial application, and QT is not free, is that true?. There are GPL Qt library that I can use for my Application and I havent this limitation?

Comment: Qt is LGPL. So you can freely use it for a commercial app. More info on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352896/qt-commercial-licenses

Comment: Ok, but not PyQt instead pyside